# How to avoid shared sessions when accessing one domain

Tags: php, iis

I am having problems regarding the shared sessions once the users logged in simultaneously to the website. When the last user logs in, every users views the account of the last user, which is not appropriate (security issue I guess). All users must login to the same website and must show an output for a specific user only.

I am using PHP code. Does anyone also experienced these scenario? here's the code

```
function validate_login(){
    $userName= trim((isset($_POST['username']) === TRUE ? $_POST['username'] : ''));
    $userPass= trim((isset($_POST['userpass']) === TRUE ? $_POST['userpass'] : ''));
    $userNameArray  = explode("@", $userName);
    $userName       = $userNameArray[0];
    $compLogin      = ((isset($userNameArray[1]) === TRUE ? $userNameArray[1]: ''));

    $KeepAlive = new KeepAlive();
    if(isset($userNameArray[1])){
    if(!$this->Login->checkattempt('admin')){
    $loginArray = array(
    'login' => $userName,
    'comp_login_string' => $compLogin,
    'pass' => $cryptography->encryptPassword($userPass)
    );

    $userCredentials = $this->Login->getLogin($loginArray);
    if(!empty($userCredentials)){
    $_SESSION['userCredentials'] = $userCredentials[0];
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $_SESSION['employee_user']  = '0';
    $_SESSION['emp_id']         = '0';
    $_SESSION['page']['client_ip_address']  = $KeepAlive->get_client_ip();
    $_SESSION['page']['last_trans_time']        = time();
    $this->Login->clear_attempt_log($_POST, 'admin');
    echo json_encode(array('id' => $userCredentials[0]['id']));
    }
    } else {
    array_shift($loginArray);
    $this->Login->attempt_log($_POST, 'admin');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('id' => '-1'));
    }
    } else {
    echo json_encode(array('id' => '-2'));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should supply the relevant code.

Comment: i edited the question with our code. it will return the session based from the username and password given by users. once logged in, usercredential will be set as session. it works with 5 users, but once the users became 10+ and they access the website, all of them will view only one session